# Android: can't understand OnClickListener syntax

Tags: android, onclicklistener

In the code:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){
        ...         
    }

});
```

Within the `button.setOnClickListener` function call, is it the case that we're (1) creating a new `Button` object, (2) calling the new `Button` object's `OnClickListener` and (3) defining a new class? Why is so much happening within a function call? Is there a way to simplify this code (e.g. maybe define the class separately outside and pass an instance to this function or something like that)?

Comment: You are only declaring a dynamic variable that references your button from your resources and setting a listener to it. You can let your class implement a single lestener though.

Answer (score 1):

the parameter of setOnClickListener has only one instantiation, which is the OnClickListener class (which happens to be defined inside the Button class, thats why you write Button.OnClickListener).
  So (1) is not happening (you are just creating a new OnClickListener object); (2) is also not happening, because OnClickListener is not a method; (3) is happening, which is an annonymous subclass of the OnClickListener class.

It is possible to create a named class for a OnClickListener subclass, it is just that it is sometimes easier to have the action code next to the code where you define your button. There you can easily refer to variables in that scope.
  But making it a named class allows you to reuse the code in other buttons.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the followings steps
 1. implements onclickListner in activity
 2. overwrite onClick method where you should write your code whatever you want
 3. and setOnClickListener on button